# joining / merging two arrays

Tags: php, collections

I have two arrays like this, actually this is mysql data retrieved from two different servers:

```
$array1 = array ( 
                  0 => array ( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'somename') ,
                  1 => array ( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'somename2') 
);
$array2 = array ( 
                  0 => array ( 'thdl_id' => 1, 'otherdate' => 'spmethings') ,
                  1 => array ( 'thdl_id' => 2, 'otherdate' => 'spmethings22') 
);
```

how can i join / merge array so it looks like this

```
$new_array = array ( 
         0 => array ( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'somename', 'otherdate' => 'spmethings') ,
         1 => array ( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'somename2', 'otherdate' => 'spmethings22') 
);
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this? Where does `thdl_id` go?

Comment: Can we assume that they're both in order and contain the same id's?

Comment: @Pekka - I think thdl_id is the same as 'id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that I'm misunderstanding, but is this what you're looking for?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
    $new_array[$i] = array_merge($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
    unset($new_array[$i]['thdl_id']); //since i'm assuming this is a duplicate of 'id'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that + check if their sizes are the same if you want..

```
$res = array()
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($array1); ++$i )
{
  $res[] = array_merge($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
}
```

Comment: good. i'd add $number = min(count($array1), count($array2)); and then just do $i < $number in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Like an `INNER JOIN`? You'll have to do it manually. I know PHP has quite a collection of exotic functions, but none do what you want as far as I know.

Think "insertion sort." Sort both arrays and walk them. Merge rows as you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array($array1, $array2);
```